# Pinescript/Tradingview indicator Alerts to a Webhook?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am trying to get the Tradingview indicator alerts to a webhook , I have already set up the webhook, but I am a bit confused about the indicator side of things...

My Use Case: I want to send Indicator signals to the webhook , but I am a bit confused about few things:

1: Do I need to keep the Tradingview Chart running (with indicator attached) in order to send the Indicator signals to the webhook?

2:what if I want to send signals from multiple Pairs/Symbol ? for Example: 32 Currency pair across all timeframes ? do I need to keep all 32 pairs open with indicator attached on the charts ?

3: What would be the best approach to send indicator signals to a webhook ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1: Do I need to keep the Tradingview Chart running (with indicator
> attached) in order to send the Indicator signals to the webhook?

No, it will run on Tradingview's server. So, you can go offline freely.

> 2:what if I want to send signals from multiple Pairs/Symbol ? for
> Example: 32 Currency pair across all timeframes ? do I need to keep
> all 32 pairs open with indicator attached on the charts ?

You just need to set individual alerts for each pair and each time frame.

> 3: What would be the best approach to send indicator signals to a
> webhook ?

Alerts is a good idea but you can only have a limited number of alerts depending on your subscription type. Please see [here](https://www.tradingview.com/gopro/) for comparision.